# How to echo the JSON array items of a callback separately?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

this is my callback, where the first item of the array is the `title` and the second is the `button`.

```
jQuery21306342411266173318_1460205778290([["I see you like this Mazda, don't you?","OK, give more info!"]])
```

On the frontend I use this, and it shows me both items. How can I get the first ( `title` ) and how the second (`button`) separately ?

```
function showPopup(data) { 
console.log(data[0]);
}

function alert(){
      $.getJSON("handler.php?type=alert&callback=?&cookie="+ y, showPopup);
}
```

Comment: Hint: It's an array in an array ;)

Comment: @Andreas got it! yes!